# Live Data in Django - Ajax

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

My aim is to add data to see on the screen whithout refreshing the page.
In this code I use un setInterval, but I don't like it.
I want to use a method that updates data only when I add new data with the admin Django.

JavaScript

```
    let tab = document.getElementById('tabella');

    setInterval(function() {
        fetch("{% url 'ajax' %}")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => {
            tab.innerHTML = '';
            for(let i in result.users) {
                var text = `<tr><td>${result.users[i].nome}</td>
                    <td>${result.users[i].cognome}</td>
                    <td>${result.users[i].telefono}</td>
                    <td>${result.users[i].email}</td></tr>`;
                tab.innerHTML += text;
            }
        });
    }, 1000)
```

views.py

```
def Home(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def Ajax(request):
    queryset = Utenti.objects.all()
    return JsonResponse({'users':list(queryset.values())})
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import Home, Ajax

urlpatterns = [
    path('', Home, name='index'),
    path('ajax', Ajax, name='ajax'),
]
```

Comment: I'm 99.99% sure you are exposing your app to cross site scripting attacks with your use of innerHTML. You should use innerText instead.

Comment: What you want to do is definitely achievable, but what you need is to use websockets.

Comment: You can watch the tutorial at https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/.

Comment: Use websockets instead for continous updating, not ajax...

Comment: OK thanks.  Is continuous updating the only way to achieve what I want?  Isn't there a feature to make the data only update if I add or edit posts?